# Calculate the date with the results of the day

Tags: php

I want to count the days in a date, the sample code that I use as below

```
<?php
  $birthDate = "12-8-2018"; ( m-d-Y)
  $birthDate = explode("-", $birthDate);
  $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthDate[0], $birthDate[1], $birthDate[2]))) > date("md")
    ? ((date("Y") - $birthDate[2]) - 1)
    : (date("Y") - $birthDate[2]));
  echo "Age is:" . $age; // OUTPUT is -1
?>
```

the results I get are only in the form of years, how do I get results in the form of the number of days, an example for the results in the code above should be 19

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple:

```
<?php
$birthDate = "12-8-2018";                   // Input date
$birthDate = strtotime($birthDate);         // Convert to unix time

$days = (time() - $birthDate)/(60*60*24);   // difference / (60 seconds*60 minutes*24 hours)
?>
```

`$days` will be float use `floor()` function to convert it to integer value:

```
echo floor($days);  // 18.674826388889 -> 18
```

[View php fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f1c2952e38e03b36e9dd0782a72f60baefc61125)